# Have an issue with React transition group's nodeRef

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group, nodereference

```js
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import "./Styles/App.css";
import Postlist from "./components/Postlist";
import MyButton from "./components/UI/button/MyButton";
import PostForm from "./components/PostForm";
import PostFilter from "./components/PostFilter";
import MyModal from "./components/UI/MyModale/MyModale";
{/* Root component */}
function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([
    { id: 1, title: "hello", body: "education" },
    { id: 2, title: "world ", body: "world" },
    { id: 3, title: "Javascript ", body: "syntax" },
  ]);

  const [filter, setFilter] = useState({ sort: "", query: "" });

  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);

  const sortedPosts = useMemo(() => {
    if (filter.sort) {
      return [...posts].sort((a, b) =>
        a[filter.sort].localeCompare(b[filter.sort])
      );
    } else {
      return posts;
    }
  }, [filter.sort, posts]);

  const sortedAndSearchedPosts = useMemo(() => {
    return sortedPosts.filter((post) =>
      post.title.toLowerCase().includes(filter.query.toLowerCase())
    );
  }, [filter.query, sortedPosts]);

  const createForm = (newPost) => {
    setPosts([...posts, newPost]);
    setModal(false);
  };
  const removePost = (post) => {
    setPosts(posts.filter((p) => p.id !== post.id));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyButton style={{ marginTop: 30 }} onClick={() => setModal(true)}>
        Create Customer
      </MyButton>

      <MyModal visible={modal} setVisible={setModal}>
        <PostForm create={createForm} />
      </MyModal>

      <hr style={{ margin: "15px 0" }} />

      <PostFilter filter={filter} setFilter={setFilter} />

      <Postlist
        remove={removePost}
        posts={sortedAndSearchedPosts}
        title="Posts about JS"
      ></Postlist>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
 
 {/*Postlist component */}
 import React from "react";
import Postitem from "./Postitem";
import { TransitionGroup, CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";
import { useRef } from "react";

const Postlist = ({ posts, title, remove }) => {
  const ref = useRef();

  if (!posts.length) {
    return <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Posts can't be found</h1>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>{title}</h1>
      <TransitionGroup>
        {posts.map((post, index) => (
          <CSSTransition
            key={post.id}
            nodeRef={ref}
            timeout={500}
            classNames="post"
          >
            <Postitem remove={remove} number={index + 1} post={post} />
          </CSSTransition>
        ))}
      </TransitionGroup>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Postlist;
```

```css
/*App.css */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#root {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.App {
  width: 800px;
}

.post {
  display: flex;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 2px solid teal;
  margin-top: 15px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.post-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.post-enter-active {
  transform: translateX(350px);
  transition: all 500ms ease-in;
}
.post-exit {
  opacity: 1;
}
.post-exit-active {
  transform: translateX(-350px);
  transition: all 500ms ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />


    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

</html>
```

Sadly my youtube guide is 1 year old and react transition group doesn't have nodeRef (in video). Was looking for any other tutorials, but could not find any fresh solution... [My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pB9Zk.png)

(Imported useRef) Tried to create variable with useRef() and connect to nodeRef . This way code started working the same way(properly), but animations are not applied . Any suggestions how to make animations work and what nodeRef stands for? (did not understand clearly what it is used for)

Comment: Post your code as text

Comment: Ideally include your code in a snippet instead of an image so others can better help solve your problem.